# Comparar item de lista uno en lista uno, python

Tags: python, lista

Soy nuevo en Python, recién estoy aprendiendo. 
Trato de hacer un programa que le soicite al usuario 5 datos y los almacene en una lista; después tiene que comparar si hay elementos repetidos y los elementos que no estén repetidos incluirlos en una nueva lista a imprimir.

Tengo poco, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho más intentos con variaciones de lo mismo y así, pero no me funciona. Intenté hacerlo con 3 valores y de ahí, una vez me saliera, ir aumentandole hasta llegar a los 6 datos. 
Como estoy aprendiendo se supone que solamente debo utilizar cosas como 'for in range' 'if' 'elif' 'or' 'and' 'else' while'; es decir lo básico. Pero no logro entender del todo como funcionan.

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, qué bueno que te adentres a la programación.

### Solución 1

Te presento un pequeño código que, si bien no es el mejor, creo que te puede ayudar a entender la lógica mejor.

```
print("Hola, a continuación ingresa los 5 datos")

user_inputs = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    user_inputs.append(input("Ingresa el dato número {}: ".format(i)))

unique_user_inputs = []
for i in user_inputs:
    exists = 0
    for j in user_inputs:
        if j == i:
            if exists == 1:
                break
            else:
                exists += 1
    if (exists < 2):
        unique_user_inputs.append(i)

print("Los elementos únicos son: {}".format(unique_user_inputs))
```

Ahora te explico el código:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    user_inputs.append(input("Ingresa el dato número {}: ".format(i)))
```

La función range recibe 2 parámetros escenciales:

1. Dónde inicia (comenzando por ahí, si se omite se sobreentiende que este es 0)
2. Dónde termina (terminando un número antes, si es 6, termina en 5)

hay un tercer parámetro opcional, que es el salto, de cuánto en cuánto va (de 1 en 1, de 2 en 2....)

Lo de `{}` y `.format`, es la *string interpolation*, que es básicamente reemplazar `{}` por los parámetros de `format`

Este for revisa si hay elementos repetidos y los únicos, los mete a otra lista

```
for i in user_inputs:
    exists = 0
    for j in user_inputs:
        # si el elemento es el mismo
        if j == i:
            # si el elemento ya se había encontrado antes
            if exists == 1:
                break
            # si el elemento no ha sido encontrado
            else:
                exists += 1
    if (exists < 2):
        unique_user_inputs.append(i)
```

### Solución 2

Aunque, el código del principio se puede mejorar de la siguiente forma:

```
print("Hola, a continuación ingresa los 5 datos")

user_inputs = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    temp_input = input("Ingresa el dato número {}: ".format(i))
    exists = False
    for j in user_inputs:
        if j == temp_input:
            exists = True
            break
    if not exists:
        user_inputs.append(temp_input)

print("Los elementos únicos son: {}".format(user_inputs))
```

Así, se hace la comprobación de elementos repetidos dentro del mismo `for` usado para crearlos, ahorrando recursos y tiempo.

### Solución 3

Por último, esto se puede simplificar aún más, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
print("Hola, a continuación ingresa los 5 datos")

user_inputs = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    user_inputs.append(input("Ingresa el dato número {}: ".format(i)))

print("Los elementos únicos son: {}".format(set(user_inputs)))
```

Este último método me parece que es el más rápido, pero no tiene la parte algorítmica que creo que es lo que buscas.

Espero haberte ayudado.